# How to install gazebo on WSL Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ros, ubuntu-20.04, gimp, gazebo-simu

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Windows machine (Windows 10) using WSL (WSL 2), and I am unable to get Gazebo to work. I first installed ROS noetic using robostack, [following the instructions from here](https://github.com/RoboStack/ros-noetic), then I installed Gazebo in the robostackenv with `conda install -c conda-forge gazebo`. Since I am using WSL, I setup vcxsrv to allow GUI windows to open, I tested this using nautilus (a file explorer application for Ubuntu) and I am able to open the GUI with no problems. However, after installing Gazebo, if I run then it, I only get the initial splash screen that looks like Gazebo is about to start, and then it just crashes with no error messages or anything. I am seeing some messages printed to the console before it crashes, which are:

```
(robostackenv) $ gazebo
NVD3D10: CPU cyclestats are disabled on client virtualization
NVD3D10: CPU cyclestats are disabled on client virtualization
NVD3D10: CPU cyclestats are disabled on client virtualization
NVD3D10: CPU cyclestats are disabled on client virtualization
NVD3D10: CPU cyclestats are disabled on client virtualization
(robostackenv) $
```

I'm not sure why Gazebo isn't loading and I'm hoping that I just need to install an extra package or something to fix it. Does anyone know how I can get it working?

One other issue that might be helpful too is that even though I AM able to run nautilus, I am also unable to run GIMP, so it is possible that this is also related to the Gazebo issue. When I run GIMP I see a very similar issue as I do when I run Gazebo, where I get the initial splash screen but then it crashes after a few seconds without actually loading anything. The error messages for GIMP are different though:

```
(robostackenv) $ gimp
Error spawning command line “dbus-launch --autolaunch=5cecfec9bed410f984c88e9f62869edc --binary-syntax --close-stderr”: Child process exited with code 1

(gimp:14200): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:30:31.771: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gimp:14200): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:30:31.771: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

...

(gimp:14200): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:30:31.772: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gimp:14200): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:30:31.772: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gimp:14200): Gtk-WARNING **: 22:30:31.773: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
gimp: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server 172.31.176.1:0.

(script-fu:14227): LibGimpBase-WARNING **: 22:30:34.541: script-fu: gimp_wire_read(): error

(robostackenv) $
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this Github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectML/issues/117#issuecomment-831672077), the first error message you are seeing is from the nVidia Preview WSL driver.

Make sure that you have the latest nVidia Windows driver installed, and hopefully that will take care of it.  That could also be related to the Gimp issue, of course.

Comment: I just checked and it looks like all of my drivers are already up to date. I have an NVIDIA T1200 laptop GPU and it has driver version 472.91

Comment: Actually I did some digging on the NVIDIA website and found a newer driver that looks to be compatible with the same graphics card, so I'll install that: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/189746/en-us

Comment: After updating the NVIDIA driver to the newest one, I am still experiencing the same issue (only get Gazebo splash screen and then it crashes), however, it is now no longer printing the `NVD3D10: CPU cyclestats are disabled on client virtualization` message anymore.

Comment: @stackoverflowing321 Apologies - I did actually chuckle at that.  We fixed the error, but not the real problem :-/.  I'll noodle on this some more and see what I can come up with.